# How do you set the js loading sequence

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, html

I have a webpage. It will load some js file. One of them is google-analytics'js ga.js file. My location is in china, so, sometimes it will be slow when loading it.

If the ga.js didn't finish loading, another js file named wmd.js will not be loaded. So, the webpage will not work properly.

So, I wonder if there are some ways of setting, than let the ga.js be loaded when all the web files are finished loading?

Below is my google-analytics setting

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '{{ settings.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_KEY }}']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'baidu', 'word']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'soso', 'w']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', '3721', 'name']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'yodao', 'q']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'vnet', 'kw']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'sogou', 'query']);

        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);

        (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    ga.setAttribute('async', 'true');
    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(ga);
        })();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Always, this should be the last script to be loaded. You should put this code at the end (before closing body tag).

Comment: currently , i was put the code at the end , and is before closing the body tag .